# selection check of select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting stuck to check StartAll & StopAll

What I want to implement is that ->

1> on selecting All checkbox, all the features(except stopall) will be selected and disabled.

2>on selecting Stopall,all the features will be unselected and disabled.

3>B,D & E's value will be slected in the textbox.

Here's the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/bigzer0/PKRVR/5/

```
<div align="center" id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="startall" data-name="Startall" class="check" id="check" value="all"> All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="stopall" data-name="Stopall" class="check" id="check" value="stopall"> STOPall &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="apple" data-name="Apple" class="check" id="check" value="a"> Apple &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="ball" data-name="Ball" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"  id="check" value="b"> Ball
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" data-name="Cat" class="check" id="check" value="c"> Cat &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dog" data-name="Dog" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"  id="check" value="d"> Dog
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="elephant" data-name="Elephant" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"  id="check" value="e">
    Elephant &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>


<input type="text" name="policyName" id="policyName" title="Policy Name" class="cpolicyname" value="Start" readonly="readonly" >

<input type="text" name="features" title="Policy Features" class="cfeatures" id="features" readonly="readonly" size="60">
```

my (nightmare)jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function(){
        $("#policyName").val('Start');
        $("#features").val('');
                  $(".check").each(function(){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){

                $("#policyName").val($("#policyName").val() + $(this).val());    
                $("#features").val($("#features").val() + $(this).data('name'));
                }            
        });

     });
});
```

Any inputs will be appreciated and welcome.

Comment: don't use the same id more than once. anyway, what is the specific problem? why just not implement three blocks of code like you explained in your three bullet points? separate and conquer...

Comment: ```$("#startall").click(function(){ if $("#startall")[0].checked) { /* startall is checked, do something with the others */  } else { /* startall is UNchecked, do something with the others */ } })```

Comment: What is your intention when using the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: yes, as well as B & D always checked and it's corresponding text value will be selected and 1> + 2> in my Questain :(

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even do it like this? You dont even check which button was clicked.
Give the checkboxes other than Stopall and Startall another class like "checkable"

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('name')=='Stopall') {
        $('.checkable').attr('disabled',true).attr('checked',false);

    } else if ($(this).attr('name')=='Startall') {
        $('.checkable').attr('disabled',true).attr('checked',true);
    }
}
```

You can give multiple classes on css like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="anything" class="class1 class2 class3" />
```

I think the rest is really at you ;)

Comment: thanks for your solution,but sametime All and Stop are selected. One more thing is that By default B & D and it's value will be selected. any inputs...

Comment: you shall ONLY give the class "checkable" to NOT "All" and "Stop"!
And the class check is ONLY given to "All" and "Stop"

Comment: i got that,but this piece of your code when I'm adding to my code,all exisiting features are getting stopped.

Comment: anyway you have to do a bit of rethinking otherwise you cant make it work. you can also take your code from above and check the names per attr('name'). THEN if its Stopall or Startall you can do something like 
$('.check').each(function(){
   /** check or uncheck all but those with Startall/Stopall name **/
};

Comment: you could also do something like this for the last part of code i wrote: $('.check').not('[name=Startall]').not('[name=Stopall]').blabla();